# Google recaptcha 404 org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException for validation of the token

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I do get 404 while validating the google recaptcha token, the code goes as below,

For google recaptcha client side configuration in

```
<div align="center">
   <input type="hidden" id="captchaResponse" name="captchaResponse" />
   <form action="?" method="POST">
       <div id="recaptcha"></div>
          <br>
   </form>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer>
   </script>
</div>

     var verifyCallback = function(response) {
            document.getElementById('captchaResponse').value = response;
          };
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.render('recaptcha', {
          'sitekey' : '${grailsApplication.config.get('recaptcha').get('key')}',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
          'theme' : 'white'
        });
      };
```

I do get a token which gets validated as below,

```
       String verifyUri = String.format(
            uri + "?secret=%s&response=%s",
            secret,
            response);
    GoogleResponse googleResponse = new GoogleResponse();
    try {
        googleResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(verifyUri, GoogleResponse.class);
    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("reCaptcha was not successfully validated");
        return false;
    }
```

But for every validation request for enterprise version of google recaptcha I get

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
```

Right now I'm using test keys for enterprise version. This I'm trying to test on local. where verify origin has been disabled.
what could be wrong to get this error. Thanks in advance.